# Converting python list to a specific javascript format

Tags: python, django, list

Using Django, I have the following model:

```
class Score(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    month = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    points = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I have the following data in this table:

```
Team    Date    Points
A   Jan 2015    100
A   Feb 2015    150
A   Mar 2015    200
B   Jan 2015    120
B   Feb 2015    200
B   Mar 2015    300
C   Jan 2015    111
C   Feb 2015    122
C   Mar 2015    133
```

So, I my view I can run:

```
data = Score.objects.all()
```

This will return a list with all the aforementioned records. So far, so good. However, I want to show this as a graph in javascript. This requires a very specific format. Firstly, I need to get all the x-axis labels separated ("Jan 2015", "Feb 2015", "Mar 2015"), and then I need to group all the scores by team. This is what the final js should look like:

```
<script>
   var timeXAxis = ["Jan 2015", "Feb 2015", "Mar 2015"]
     var timeSeries = [
     {
       name: "Team 1",
       data: [
         ["Jan 2015", 100],
         ["Feb 2015", 150],
         ["Mar 2015", 200],
       ]
     },
     {
       name: "Team 2",
       data: [
         ["Jan 2015", 120],
         ["Feb 2015", 200],
         ["Mar 2015", 300],
       ]
     },
     {
       name: "Team 3",
       data: [
         ["Jan 2015", 111],
         ["Feb 2015", 222],
         ["Mar 2015", 333],
       ]
     }
   ];
</script>
```

This is where it gets tricky. I am new to python and not sure what the right way is of doing this. I assume I should prepare the variables in my view, and not do much of this in my template. But how should I go about this? Do I create two lists (one for the x-axis labels, and then another for the data)? Do I use multidimensional lists? Or dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to have the data be represented as is JSON format. For this, your data gathered from `data = Score.objects.all()` should be ***serialized*** and passed to template as JSON.

Small example:

```
from django.core import serializers

def get_modelAPI(request):
    SomeModel_json = serializers.serialize("json", SomeModel.objects.all())
    data = {"SomeModel_json": SomeModel_json}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

For more, you should read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But JSON isn't really the format in which I need the information. Is this the only way to go? I then need to use js to parse the script into the right format? No way to get it into a specific other format with Django?

Comment: Like if you do not serialize, Django will send the data in object form and in javascript, you will not be able to use it. Only through template tags of Django. But json you can get wit ajax which runs in the background and it is easy and straightforward to shape it as you wish. And your data is so much alike with json format.

Comment: Noted. Thanks a lot for your help!